# Proximal Operator of a Composition of Functions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

Is there a way to compute the proximal operator for the composition of two functions $f \circ g(x)$ using $\mathrm{prox}_{f}$ and $\mathrm{prox}_{g}$? If $g(x) = A x$ is a semi-orthogonal linear map ($A A^* = I$), one has

$$
 \mathrm{prox}_{f \circ A}(x) = A^*\ \mathrm{prox}_{f}(A x).
$$

Is there a similar result for weaker conditions on $g(x)$?

Comment: I doubt you'll get very far with anything nonlinear. Linear/affine, perhaps.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelGrant that all bets are probably off.

Comment: Hmm, thanks though :)

Comment: Have a look at - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3310302/33.